# MySQL multiple result rows in stored function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I've written a MySQL function that calculates a price:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`[USER]`@`[HOST]` FUNCTION `calculatePrice`(id INT) 
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF id=10 THEN 
        RETURN 899;
    ELSE
        RETURN 710;
    END IF;
END
```

This works how it should, but next to the price, I want to add a string containing the reason of the price.

That function should be used like this:

```
SELECT id, calculatePrice(id).price AS price, calculatePrice(id).reason AS reason FROM person;
```

Is this possible with MySQL and how does it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really, really need to do the calculation in the database? Maybe try to rethink the problem from a higher level? Given some more context, we might be able to come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

how about taking two parameters on it and the value will depend according to the second parameter, example

```
CREATE DEFINER=`[USER]`@`[HOST]` FUNCTION `calculatePrice`(id INT, isPrice INT) 
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF isPrice = 1 THEN -- for price
        IF id = 10 THEN 
            RETURN 899;
        ELSE
            RETURN 710;
        END IF;
    ELSE                -- for reason
        IF id = 10 THEN 
            RETURN 100;
        ELSE
            RETURN 200;
        END IF;
    END IF
END
```

and call it like

```
SELECT  id, 
        calculatePrice(id, 1) AS price, 
        calculatePrice(id, 0).reason AS reason 
FROM person;
```

but if you don't like the idea, just make two separate function that suit your needs.

Comment: Your solution is possible but the problem is that `calculatePrice` get's called twice. In this example it's tiny and fast, but in the real application it's very large, calling it twice would generate a serious delay...

Writing two different functions isn't a great answer for the same reason, and it's hardly maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You can 
1) Change the Return type to varchar
2) Return With Concatinating the price and description

using the function CONCAT(price,',',desc)